# Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module customerApp due to: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

I'm getting the error "Unknown provider: $routeProvider" even though I have `ngRoute` as dependency and have included `angular-route.js` in the HTML files

```
var customerAppModule = angular.module("customerApp", ['ngRoute']);
customerAppModule.config(['$routeProvider',
    function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/MainMenu', {
                templateUrl: 'Home/MainMenu.html',
                controller: 'CheckCtrl'
            }).
            when('/Index', {
                templateUrl: 'Home/Index.html',
                controller: 'MainCtrl'
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/MainMenu'
            });
    }]);
```

Comment: That's highly unlikely. Usually you'll see this error when angular-route.js is not loaded. If it's included in html but isn't loaded, this won't really help. Please, provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the problem. A fiddle or plunk will be ok.

Comment: @estus when I remove the route configuration which I have showed in the post, the problem disappear. Since I don't know which part of the code of my project to put in the plunk, would you mind if I upload the visual studio project and give you the link so that you can have a look?

Comment: This will probably work. That's not just for me but for anyone who can help.

Comment: [here is the project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1ORPxuULIaNWmVNaUtFRzhzVVk/view?usp=sharing) I'm retrieving data from an API which in found in "Controllers/CustomerController". The only javascript file is found in "Scripts/app". My first view is "Index.cshtml" found in "Views/Home". When you launch "Index.cshtml" you'll notice it doesn't work as it should except if you remove the routing configuration which I posted above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this error appears when angular-route.js is not loaded for some reason.

The said project has mismatched versions for angular and its module:

```
<script data-require="angular.js@1.4.0-beta.6" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.6" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.6/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
```

This can result in injector failure but will also produce other errors.

Comment: so what is the solution?

Comment: Make these versions match. They should likely be `.../1.6.4/angular.js` and  `.../1.6.4/angular-route.js`.